# How to Select every 5000th Number from DB in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table named tickets, I want to fetch every 5000th Number , 
Like first will be id number 5000
2nd will be 10000
So on.

Comment: What if there are gaps in the ids?

Comment: Its doesn't matter

Comment: . . Of course it matters.  The data might be missing ids 5000, 10000 and so on.  Then your description of the question would return nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a numeric primary key (for example "id"), you could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE id % 5000 = 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

If the IDs are not continuous you could always simulate row number:

```
SET @rn=0;
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rn
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY id
) t
WHERE rn % 5000 = 0;
```

Here is a simplified demo with non continuous `id` values showing that this approach can work:

### Demo